# Why is the output different?

Tags: c

Please explain me why it behaves differently.

```
  int main() {
    int p;
    p = (printf("stack"),printf("overflow"));
    printf("%d",p);
    return 0;
  }
```

This gives the output as stackoverflow8. However , if I remove the paranthesis , then :

`p = printf("stack"),printf("overflow");` gives the output as `stackoverflow5`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[The Comma Operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator)

The comma operator has lower precedence than assignment (it has a lower precedence than *any* operator for that matter), so if you remove the parentheses the assignment takes place first and the result of the second expression is discarded.  So...

```
int a = 10, b = 20;
int x = (a,b); // x == 20
int y = a,b;   // y == 10
// equivalent (in terms of assignment) to
//int y = a;
```

Note that the third line will cause an error as it is interpreted as a re-declaration of `b`, i.e.:

```
int y = a;
int b;
```

I missed this at first, but it makes sense.  It is no different than the initial declaration of `a` and `b`, and in this case the comma is not an operator, it is a separator.

Comment: int y = a,b;  is equivalent to int y = a; and int b;

Comment: @EdS.   I tried your code with gcc, and the 3rd statement does give a "redeclaration of 'b'" and "previous definition of 'b'" error.

Comment: @abelenky: Ahh, so it does, I get the same.  I didn't catch that when I mentally parsed it, but it makes sense.  Thanks.